# Django - ImageField, upload, store and serve image in development server

Tags: django, django-models, django-staticfiles, imagefield

I'd like to have an ImageField in the admin form for my model (say, for an individual's profile). And I'd like to display this image in a view later on.

This is the model I have :

```
class Individual(models.Model):
    ind_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ind_photo = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ind_name
```

This is what I have in the settings for my website :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static/media")
```

These are the urls of my app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index")
]
```

I know how to use static files (e.g. CSS, Javascript), and to get them to work in both development and production. 
But I have no clue how to get images to work. I've read [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user) and [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/), but I still don't get it.

With the code above the image gets saved in the proper folder (i.e. /static/media at the level of my site). But I have no clue :

1) how to display it in a template,

2) whether it would be best to keep these images in my app's static folder,

3) and (if 2) whether I would need to run collectstatic every time someone uploads an image in the admin.

Sorry if I'm unclear, but this way more obscure than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the image to be uploaded and served during development, I had to move the media folder out of the static folder (i.e. create a media folder at the root of my project's folder).

And in my main urls.py, I had to add :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

as suggested by MicroPyramid.

To display it in a template, for a given Individual "somebody" (from a queryset), I use :

```
<img src="{{ somebody.ind_photo.url }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to separate both staticfiles and media files. Yes, you have to do collectstatic all the time when you upload if you store the images in static folder. We can get the image full url from the object like the following.

```
{{obj.ind_photo.url}}
```

For more info on files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/files/

Comment: I can't display this image with this in the development server. The url is correct path, but it's not served. Also, if I need to run collectstatic every time an image is uploaded in the admin, where should I hook this ? In the save method for my model ?

Comment: In general in development/production environment we will be serving the static or media files with webserver. So you have to configure the path of your media directory in your webserver.

Comment: I think I can get it to work in production, but I need to test stuff during development. So how can I serve the image while running the development server ?

Comment: Keep `if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in your urls.py

Comment: I've tried this in both my app's and my site's urls.py and it still doesn't serve the image. :(

Comment: Oh this is wierd, can you give the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT and the result of the path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134978/discussion-between-guitarextended-and-micropyramid).